# The tags [sort] and [sorting]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have two tags which, I think, should be merged / become synonyms:

- [sort](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sort) (× 68)

  > putting items into order, for example alphabetic.
- [sorting](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sorting) (× 87)

  > any process of arranging items in some sequence and/or in different sets

Currently 9 questions use [both tags](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sort+sorting).